# Generating the standard ASP.NET 'uncaught exception' page HTML from the exception itself?

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

Is it possible to generate the HTML page normally shown for an uncaught exception in ASP.NET, using an **Exception** object?

I have an app that catches an exception in **Global.asax -> Application_Error**, and does a **Server.Transfer()** to our pretty general-error page. I have an **#if DEBUG** flag that's pulling out the Exception from **Server.GetLastError()** and is currently custom formatting it.

But now I'm curious if I can get the HTML normally given, and put it in something like the link from a jQuery ThickBox overlay...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

- The exception is an HttpException: call **[GetHtmlErrorMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.gethtmlerrormessage.aspx)** and get the HTML.
- The exception is not an HttpException: call `new HttpException (exc.Message, exc).GetHtmlErrorMessage ()`.

Comment: + a touch-up, if anyone has issues - http://www.groupsrv.com/dotnet/about217784.html

Comment: Ah, yes. That problem might happen if HttpContext.Current is not set for the thread.

Comment: Note: I had to create a `new HttpUnhandledException` to wrap my original exception in order for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you can actually get ACCESS to the generated HTML while catching the error, but you already have all the information you neeed in the Exception object, so you can easily generate an identical page:

- It's simply a matter of generating an error, then View->Source in IE .. copy + paste in your error page, then replace the error text bits. Basically you use the StackTrace and the Message properties of the exception..

Comment: Oh, I'm aware the exception has all I need - I'm currently rendering a custom formatting of it.

I'm curious if I can get MS's version in a single method call...